# Why does Azure Cognitive Search Indexer Create Base64 names unnecessarily?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-cognitive-search

I'm trying to use Native Soft Blob Delete on Azure Cognitive Search (per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-index-changed-deleted-blobs) to delete when files are deleted from a container, and thus delete the files from the Index, but it is not going as I expect nor as the documentation provides.

1. I have created a Storage account with "Enable Soft Delete for Blobs" turned on.  Then I create a storage container within that account.
2. I have created a Data Source to use that container with the following settings (JSON):

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://sotestservice1.search.windows.net/$metadata#datasources/$entity",
  "@odata.etag": "\"0x8DC3D5D3E87D000\"",
  "name": "sotestdatasource1",
  "description": null,
  "type": "azureblob",
  "subtype": null,
  "credentials": { 
    "connectionString": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=soteststorageaccount;AccountKey=OMITTED;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
  },
  "container": {
    "name": "sotestcontainer"
  },
  "dataChangeDetectionPolicy": null,
  "dataDeletionDetectionPolicy": {
    "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.NativeBlobSoftDeleteDeletionDetectionPolicy"
  },
  "encryptionKey": null,
  "identity": null
}
```

3. I created an index on Azure Cognitive Search, with the following settings (JSON):

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://sotestservice1.search.windows.net/$metadata#indexes/$entity",
  "@odata.etag": "\"0x8DC3D5CD0D66187\"",
  "name": "sotestindex1",
  "defaultScoringProfile": null,
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "id",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "searchable": false,
      "filterable": false,
      "retrievable": true,
      "sortable": false,
      "facetable": false,
      "key": true,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "analyzer": null,
      "normalizer": null,
      "dimensions": null,
      "vectorSearchProfile": null,
      "synonymMaps": []
    },
    {
      "name": "title",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "searchable": true,
      "filterable": false,
      "retrievable": true,
      "sortable": false,
      "facetable": false,
      "key": false,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "analyzer": "standard.lucene",
      "normalizer": null,
      "dimensions": null,
      "vectorSearchProfile": null,
      "synonymMaps": []
    },
    {
      "name": "content",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "searchable": true,
      "filterable": false,
      "retrievable": true,
      "sortable": false,
      "facetable": false,
      "key": false,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "analyzer": "standard.lucene",
      "normalizer": null,
      "dimensions": null,
      "vectorSearchProfile": null,
      "synonymMaps": []
    },
    {
      "name": "titleVector",
      "type": "Collection(Edm.Single)",
      "searchable": true,
      "filterable": false,
      "retrievable": true,
      "sortable": false,
      "facetable": false,
      "key": false,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "analyzer": null,
      "normalizer": null,
      "dimensions": 4,
      "vectorSearchProfile": "vector-profile-1709674759253",
      "synonymMaps": []
    },
    {
      "name": "contentVector",
      "type": "Collection(Edm.Single)",
      "searchable": true,
      "filterable": false,
      "retrievable": true,
      "sortable": false,
      "facetable": false,
      "key": false,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "analyzer": null,
      "normalizer": null,
      "dimensions": 4,
      "vectorSearchProfile": "vector-profile-1709674759253",
      "synonymMaps": []
    }
  ],
  "scoringProfiles": [],
  "corsOptions": null,
  "suggesters": [],
  "analyzers": [],
  "normalizers": [],
  "tokenizers": [],
  "tokenFilters": [],
  "charFilters": [],
  "encryptionKey": null,
  "similarity": {
    "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.BM25Similarity",
    "k1": null,
    "b": null
  },
  "semantic": null,
  "vectorSearch": {
    "algorithms": [
      {
        "name": "vector-config-1709674581416",
        "kind": "hnsw",
        "hnswParameters": {
          "metric": "cosine",
          "m": 4,
          "efConstruction": 400,
          "efSearch": 500
        },
        "exhaustiveKnnParameters": null
      }
    ],
    "profiles": [
      {
        "name": "vector-profile-1709674759253",
        "algorithm": "vector-config-1709674581416",
        "vectorizer": null
      }
    ],
    "vectorizers": []
  }
}
```

4. I created an indexer to use the Datasource from #2 and the Index from #3

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://sotestservice1.search.windows.net/$metadata#indexers/$entity",
  "@odata.etag": "\"0x8DC3D5F31973528\"",
  "name": "sotestindexer1",
  "description": null,
  "dataSourceName": "sotestdatasource1",
  "skillsetName": null,
  "targetIndexName": "sotestindex1",
  "disabled": null,
  "schedule": null,
  "parameters": {
    "batchSize": null,
    "maxFailedItems": null,
    "maxFailedItemsPerBatch": null,
    "base64EncodeKeys": null,
    "configuration": {
      "indexedFileNameExtensions": ".json",
      "parsingMode": "json"
    }
  },
  "fieldMappings": [],
  "outputFieldMappings": [],
  "cache": null,
  "encryptionKey": null
}
```

5. I uploaded JSON documents per below:

AbrahamLincoln.json:

```
{
    "id": "https---en-wikipedia-org-wiki-Abraham-Lincoln",
    "content": "Lincoln was born into poverty in a log cabin in Kentucky and was raised on the frontier, primarily in Indiana.", 
    "contentVector": [-0.7, 0.3, 0.9, -0.8], 
    "title": "Abraham Lincoln", 
    "titleVector": [0.6, -0.7, 0.2, 0.4], 
    "@search.action": "mergeOrUpload"
}
```

FranklinRoosevelt.json:

```
{
    "id": "https----en-wikipedia-org-wiki-Franklin-D-Roosevelt",
    "content": "A member of the Delano family and Roosevelt family, after attending university, Roosevelt began to practice law in New York City.", 
    "contentVector": [0.5, 0.9, 0.3, 0.4], 
    "title": "Franklin D. Roosevelt", 
    "titleVector": [0.7, 0.1, 0.8, -0.3], 
    "@search.action": "mergeOrUpload"
}
```

6. I run the indexer it gives me success (2 Documents), and '*' searches against the index return the two documents, exactly as expected.  Up until this point, I am good.
7. I delete AbrahamLincoln.json from the storage container.
8. I re-run the indexer, which succeeds.
9. Here, I would expect the index to only contain a single document at this point.  Instead, it contains *three*.  My original two documents, and a additional document that looks like this:

```
   {
      "id": "aHR0cHM6Ly9zb3Rlc3RzdG9yYWdlYWNjb3VudC5ibG9iLmNvcmUud2luZG93cy5uZXQvc290ZXN0Y29udGFpbmVyL0ZyYW5rbGluUm9vc2V2ZWx0Lmpzb241",
      "title": "Franklin D. Roosevelt",
      "content": "A member of the Delano family and Roosevelt family, after attending university, Roosevelt began to practice law in New York City.",
      "titleVector": [
        0.7,
        0.1,
        0.8,
        -0.3
      ],
      "contentVector": [
        0.5,
        0.9,
        0.3,
        0.4
      ]
    }
```

So now I'm confused, because there are 3 documents instead of 1, and this third document is a duplicate of the existing Document.  In addition, it has a new id that is Base64 encoded of the URL of the blob (with a number stuck on the end to indicate how many ='s there should be).

Is Cognitive Search doing something wrong here, or am I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For [Native blob soft delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-index-changed-deleted-blobs?tabs=portal#native-blob-soft-delete), there are some [requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-index-changed-deleted-blobs?tabs=portal#requirements-for-native-soft-delete) to be satisfied. One of them is:

> - Document keys for the documents in your index must be mapped to either a blob property or blob metadata, such as "metadata_storage_path".

So, you need to map the key either to a blob property or blob metadata.

Modify your index definition like below:

```json
{
  "@odata.context": "https://jgsai.search.windows.net/$metadata#indexes/$entity",
  "@odata.etag": "\"0x8DC3D9565D5ADC9\"",
  "name": "azureblob-index-2",
  "defaultScoringProfile": "",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "id",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      .........
    },
    {
      "name": "title",
      "type": "Edm.String",
     .........
    },
    {
      "name": "content",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      .........
    },
    {
      "name": "titleVector",
      "type": "Collection(Edm.Double)",
      .........
    },
    {
      "name": "contentVector",
      "type": "Collection(Edm.Double)",
      .........
    },
    {
      "name": "metadata_storage_path",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "searchable": false,
      "filterable": false,
      "retrievable": true,
      "sortable": false,
      "facetable": false,
      "key": true,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "analyzer": null,
      "normalizer": null,
      "dimensions": null,
      "vectorSearchProfile": null,
      "synonymMaps": []
    }
  ],
  "scoringProfiles": [],
  "corsOptions": null,
  "suggesters": [],
  "analyzers": [],
  "normalizers": [],
  "tokenizers": [],
  "tokenFilters": [],
  "charFilters": [],
  "encryptionKey": null,
  "similarity": {
    "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.BM25Similarity",
    "k1": null,
    "b": null
  },
  "semantic": null,
  "vectorSearch": null
}
```

Here i have added meta data `metadata_storage_path` and made that as key.

Next, the base64 encrypted key you are getting because of either you given

`base64EncodeKeys` as `true` or giving mapping function as `base64Encode` in mappings field.

Below is the definition of indexer.

```json
{
  "@odata.context": "https://jgsai.search.windows.net/$metadata#indexers/$entity",
  "@odata.etag": "\"0x8DC3D95C7751E0D\"",
  "name": "azureblob-indexer",
  "description": "",
  "dataSourceName": "blobsource",
  "skillsetName": null,
  "targetIndexName": "azureblob-index-2",
  "disabled": null,
  "schedule": null,
  "parameters": {
    "batchSize": null,
    "maxFailedItems": 0,
    "maxFailedItemsPerBatch": 0,
    "base64EncodeKeys": null,
    "configuration": {
      "dataToExtract": "contentAndMetadata",
      "parsingMode": "json"
    }
  },
  "fieldMappings": [
    {
      "sourceFieldName": "metadata_storage_path",
      "targetFieldName": "metadata_storage_path",
      "mappingFunction": {
        "name": "base64Encode",
        "parameters": null
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputFieldMappings": [],
  "cache": null,
  "encryptionKey": null
}
```

In this case, if you set `base64EncodeKeys` to true or `base64Encode` in `mappingFunction`, you will get a base64 encrypted key.

Data source definition.

```json
{
  "@odata.context": "https://jgsai.search.windows.net/$metadata#datasources/$entity",
  "@odata.etag": "\"0x8DC3D923FFB589D\"",
  "name": "blobsource",
  "description": null,
  "type": "azureblob",
  "subtype": null,
  "credentials": {
    "connectionString": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=jgsblob;AccountKey=..."
  },
  "container": {
    "name": "data",
    "query": "json"
  },
  "dataChangeDetectionPolicy": null,
  "dataDeletionDetectionPolicy": {
    "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.NativeBlobSoftDeleteDeletionDetectionPolicy"
  },
  "encryptionKey": null,
  "identity": null
}
```

I have got successfully output on removing the json file.

[image]

Initially, there were 2 documents. After deleting 1 and re-running the indexer, I got 1 document in the index.

Comment: base64EncodeKeys were set to 'null' (I created it through the Azure Portal, so I believe this is the correct value that is opposite to 'true').  I didn't include the indexer definition in my original question due to a copy/paste error, so you weren't to know this, but I have included it now for others and it should be apparent.  So I don't think the problem had anything to do with the base64EncodeKeys setting.

I will try the addition of the 'metadata_storage_path' option and retry the index as you said, and report back so that you and others can see if this solves the problem.

Comment: @JayashankerGS 's solution worked for me.  I had to recreate the index with metadata_storage_path as they described.  However, this meant that I also had to change my config so that id was no longer the key.  This was fine for my application, but I thought I'd mention it.  Also, I had to turn on base64EncodeKeys on the Indexer, because metadata_storage_path uses characters like ':' and '/', which is not allowed in the keys.  The end result was a metadata_storage_path encoded as UTF-16 (which was surprising but workable).

Comment: Glad it worked and it's good you mentioned your work around.